# How to display Nested Attributes in Underscore Java script Templates

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, jquery-templates

I have a backbone model nutrition item which holds quantity, percent and unit of measurement. for example

```
var nut = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {
    quantity: '0',
    percent: 0,
    uom: 'g',
}
});
```

And i have another model which contains the whole nutrition of product

```
var nutrition = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults:{
servingSize: new nut(),
calories: new nut(),
caloriesFromFat: new nut(),
totalFat: new nut(),
saturatedFat: new nut(),
cholesterol: new nut(),
sodium: new nut(),
totalCarbohydrate: new nut(),
dietaryFiber: new nut(),
sugars: new nut(),
protein: new nut(),
vitaminA: new nut(),
vitaminC: new nut(),
calcium: new nut(),
iron: new nut(),    
},
});
```

But when am printing the nutrition by passing nutrition model to the underscore template am seeing undefined. Is it underscore wont support nested attributes ?

```
<tr>
<td><strong>Total Fat <%=totalFat.quantity%> <%=totalFat.uom%></strong></td>
<td class="dv"><%=totalFat.percent+'%'%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="sub">Saturated Fat <%=saturatedFat.quantity%> <%=saturatedFat.uom%></td>
 <td class="dv"><%=saturatedFat.percent+'%'%></td>
 </tr>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `nutrition.toJSON()` or `_.clone(nutrition.attributes)` to the template.

Otherwise you get the model object, not the raw data.

To get every sub-attributes, you could to recurse through the nested attributes to expose them directly. Otherwise, you can access them directly via the `attributes` object. e.g. `cholesterol.attributes.<attr>`

Comment: i am already passing nutrition.toJSON() to the template will try clone one

Comment: This is because sub models are not parsed by `toJSON`. You could access them directly via the `attributes` object. e.g. `cholesterol.attributes.<attr>`

Answer (score 1):

The properties of a Backbone model are not directly accessible on the object itself. You should use

```
<%= totalFat.attributes.quantity %>
```

- http://backbonejs.org/#Model-attributes